# React Native fetch stalls without return or error

Tags: android, react-native, fetch-api, react-native-0.68.2

I'm currently building a React Native Android app and I'm trying to do a simple fetch inside my Code.

```js
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8081/assets/src/...',{
    method: 'GET'
})
```

There is absolutely no output from this call. No Error, no Return. When logging the Metro Server, there is not even a request coming in. The code stalls completely. I tried it with an `XMLHttpRequest` but the result is almost identical. The only difference is that the server gets the request. `onerror` or `onload` are never called.

What I've tried so far:

- `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` added to manifest xml
- `inlineRequires: true,` in metro config
- used `XMLHttpRequest`
- `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` is set

I Really hope someone can help me!

My Current package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.7",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^3.18.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "^0.8.0",
    "async-storage": "^0.1.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1170.0",
    "expo": "^45.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "^8.5.0",
    "expo-camera": "^12.2.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-file-system": "^14.0.0",
    "expo-gl": "^11.3.0",
    "expo-gl-cpp": "^11.3.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "^0.9.2",
    "ffmpeg-kit-react-native": "^4.5.2",
    "geolib": "^3.3.3",
    "graphql": "^16.5.0",
    "graphql-ws": "^5.9.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-battery": "^0.1.18",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-polyfill-globals": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^2.13.5",
    "text-encoding": "^0.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.67.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a response when sending it with Postman or when accessing the URL with your browser?

Comment: yes, response is correct when using postman or browser

Comment: Seeing this same behaviour after recently updating.
Dev works fine, Issue only happens on release build on both emulator and real device.

Comment: Did you ever made any progress on this @Slice ?

Answer (score 0):

If your response from Postman and from the Browser looks good then its probably the fact that you are using localhost wich the Emulator cant understand.

Try to use your IP Adress (the one from your PC where the Emulator runs).

So instead of: `fetch('http://localhost:8081/assets/src`...

use: `fetch('http://localIPaddressFromYourPC:8081/assets/src`

Comment: does not change the behaviour. Even if I fetch an HTTPS API the result is the same.

With `XMLHttpRequest` the local server receives a request, so localhost is reachable for the app.

Comment: Well how are you displaying your result that should be there? Maybe thats your error.

Comment: It's a simple console log after the await, and that is never shown. The data of the request is binary. The promise of fetch is never resolved nor rejected. It stays "pending"

Comment: Just tried the same code in a RN0.67.4 app and it works like expected.

Comment: Glad to here that!